# How can I get access to a private array using Java reflection?

Tags: java, arrays, reflection, minecraft

Ok I was trying to figure this out on my own but I am kinda stumped. I am trying to fix some code errors in a mod for minecraft. I got a lot of the fixed except for this one.

Basically this guys mod wants to gain access to an array in the superclass which it extends called `field_94586_c`. When the code was written that variable was public scoped. Now in the later versions it has been changed to a private scope. I was playing around with Java reflection to try and gain access to the variable so I can write the needed data to it.

Here the code snippet that applies...

```
@Override
@SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
/**
 * Gets an icon index based on an item's damage value
 */
public Icon getIconFromDamage(int par1)
{

    if (par1 < 0 || par1 >= skullTypes.length) {
        par1 = 0;
    }

    return field_94586_c[par1];
}

@Override
@SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
public void registerIcons(IconRegister par1IconRegister)
{

    field_94586_c = new Icon[field_94587_a.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < field_94587_a.length; ++i)
        if (i >= 5)
            field_94586_c[i] = par1IconRegister.registerIcon("iguanatweakstconstruct:" + field_94587_a[i]);
        else
            field_94586_c[i] = par1IconRegister.registerIcon(getIconString() + "_" + field_94587_a[i]);
}
```

Basically I need to write a modified version of the array to the superclass. He adds a few new items to the array.

My original attempt was to use a "reflector" class to return an object to me. But the issue I cannot figure out how to turn the Object into a `Icon[]`. I tried casting it but Java complains that is not possible. I don't have the original error.

Here is my reflector class...

```
package iguanaman.iguanatweakstconstruct.util;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

/**
* Created by Ian on 4/10/2014.
*/
public class IguanaReflector {

public static Object modifyAccess(final String className, final String filedName) throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

    final Field field = Class.forName(className).getDeclaredField(filedName);
    field.setAccessible(true);

    return field.get(Class.forName(className));

}
```

}

Its not much and to be honest its based on some looking around on the net.

The full package name I am trying to access is `net.minecraft.item.ItemSkull` and the field is `field_94586_c`.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is it an _instance_ field or a `static` field? Have you read the javadoc of `Field#get(Object)`?

Comment: Its an instance I am pretty sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance field is attached to an instance. It doesn't exist on its own.

The [`Field#get(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) method javadoc states

> Returns the value of the field represented by this Field, **on the
>   specified object.** The value is automatically wrapped in an object if
>   it has a primitive type.

In other words, you need to call `get` by passing the object (the instance) on which to *get* the field value (or `null` if the field is `static`). You're passing the `Class` object for the class that the field is declared in.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow... Because the what I thought I was doing with my reflector class was returning the object which was the array. So what do I need to `get` then? That the part where I am stuck.

Comment: @Solignis Forget about your class for a second. Look at the `Field#get(Object)` method javadoc. It's expects an argument which is the instance from which the field will be retrieved. So if my `Person` class has a `personName` field I wanted to retrieve, then I would call it with `theFieldObjectForPersonName.get(somePersonObject)`. You're not doing that. The object you're passing to `get` is a `Class`. In my previous example, it's as if you did `theFieldObjectForPersonName.get(Person.class)`.

Comment: turns out I run in to a slight problem. My reflection class won't survive obfuscation I found out. So...

Comment: @Solignis Not much you can do there.

Comment: I am gonna ask the Minecraft Forge people, this problem is more centered around them, thanks for the help anyway I appreciate it.

Comment: @Solignis You're welcome. Good luck. Did you understand what I was trying to explain though?

Comment: Yeah I understand the concept. The issue is I think for me to truly understand it I need to work on something that is NOT minecraft. The code for the game is very "connected" and probably not a good place to work a new concept like reflection. I should start with something small first.